# creating a basic voltage regulator

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, potentiometer

How do I create a simple voltage regulator for a 120V input voltage. The voltage regulator basically need to send an output of 25%, 50% and 75% of the input. Can this be done by simply using a bunch of resistors?

Comment: Resistors don't regulate the voltage, it will change with load current.  Is your input voltage AC or DC?  Do you want the output to be AC or DC?  How much current do you need?  What's your efficiency requirement?  What's your tolerance for output ripple? I could go on but if you answer those questions we can at least start to have a conversation.

Comment: These requirements are strange. Especially the 25% / 50% / 75% thing. You should tell us more about the whole picture (what will be after the regulator), because it gives me a strong feeling of XY problem.

Comment: Assuming you mean 120VAC power mains (not 120V DC) and do not require isolation, an `autotransformer` or `variac` is a better way to adjust the voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a resistive divider followed by a buffer amplifier. Depending on the output current and the voltage accuracy required, you'll use either an NPN power transistor or a Darlington pair:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8MZdb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you need all three voltages simultaneously, eliminate the switches and use three separate transistors.

Comment: This is fine if the OP is referring to DC power, else...